# Laravel / PHP how to find the sequence (1th, 2nd, 3d, nth) of a value in collection

Tags: php, laravel

So my aim is to check if a value exist in Collection and then get the sequence of that value in that collection like if its 1st or 20th or 243th. We can find if value exist in collection with "contains" but the sequence?.. I tried to search and look how to get it but I couldnt find anything useful.

Any ideas how I can do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To find the index of the item you're looking for, you could use the [`search`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections#method-search) method. The [Laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections#method-search) gives this example:

```
$collection = collect([2, 4, 6, 8]);

$collection->search(4);
```

The search method here will return `1` which refers to the first index that the searched for value `4` was found. Similarly you could do `$collection->search(8)` and it would return `3`.

Comment: Ah yeah.. I checked it actually i missed and read it wrong.. but anyways this is true answer and this can help people like me. thank you!

Comment: You're welcome :) Please consider marking it as accepted if it's what you were looking for.

Comment: Btw In my collection there is different values, and I will use search with user_id, do you think it will find that row in collection with user_id?

Comment: It all depends on what exactly your collection contains and what exactly you're searching for, it will match the first element that it finds to be equal (`==`) to what you're searching for. If you have a set of `User` objects, you *could* use `$collection->pluck('id')` to extract the set of IDs into another collection and then use `->search($userId)` to find the index you're looking for. All depends on your exact use case though.

Comment: Thanks for answering, it helped me a lot I guess. You explained very nice and clear thank you a lot again Jonathon! :)